# unable to loop through cells in a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagrid which returns 4 columns and 244 rows. The 4th column has 3 different statuses "Completed", "In-Progress", "NotSarted" all though out the cells. I need to loop through each cell in the 4th column and read the value add them up and store them in a varibale.So i need to have 3 variables fort he 3 statuses. How do I do ths?

```
Here is the code that I have. I am not sure if this is the right way to do it or if there is
```

an easier way, the problem with this is after I run it it keeps telling me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
listNames = new List<string>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        int i = 0;
                if (cell.Value.ToString() == "Completed")
                {
                   i ++;
                   i += i;
                }  
                MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If there is a datasource, you'd be better off working with that

Comment: The cell has obviously no value.  Why loop through the cells if you only care about ColumnIndex 3?

Comment: also you declare an `int i` but you never increment it.. I will post something so that you can easily use to follow an perhaps you will understand what's going on by stepping thru the code using the debugger..

Comment: If the DGV is `AllowUserToAddRows` == true, you are looping thru one row too many as explained in [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/26761773#26761773)

Comment: @MethodMan Thanks I will be waiting on it

Comment: also you should have this outside the for loop ` int i = 0;` and then inside of the for loop last line should be `i++;` if you use the debugger you will see exactly where you are going wrong in regards to comparison use `.Equals when comparing Objects use == when comparing Values`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count them, try this

```
var iRows = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>();
var statusLookup = iRows.ToLookup(r => r.Cells[3].Value + ""); 
int countOfCompleted = statusLookup["Completed"].Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like cell.Value can be null, so replace

```
if  (cell.Value.Equals("Completed"))
```

with

```
if  (cell.Value == "Completed")
```

Anyway String == operator is overloaded to make comparsion by value so this code will run OK

Answer (score 0):

Look at this and test it using the debugger step through the code and understand what's going on with this simple example.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(cell.Value));
    }
}
```

Comment: just did it. it is going through each cell row by row.

Comment: now take this example and change the inner foreach to fit what it is you're trying to do.. also look at my comment about where to initialize your counter, in your case `i` should be on the outside of the inner foreach loop.

Comment: Ok let me try. Will let you know if it works in a few. Thanks

Comment: Well, I used an if ststement to loop through the cells but I can't get the total results for each Status. here is the loop                                            if (cell.Value.ToString() == "Completed")
                    {
                       i ++;
                        i += i; 
                    }